# Opshub Users mapping not showing complete list of users ?

Tags: opshub

I am having a issue migrating projects to visual studo online, i am using the ops hub utilty but when i get to the mapping users screen it is not showing  complete list of users form our directory . Please advise

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the relevant users as Team Members/Readers/Contributors. (typically, you will have to make them a part of valid users of the project) and they'll load up in the user mapping screen.

Considering large number of users at collection level who may or may-not be part of all the projects, the newer version of the tool has been modified to load only users of the project(s) that are selected for migration making the user-mapping a little more convenient.